# Java Mail Error : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am stuck with the mail sending with Java Mail API.

I am not able to connect SMTP server with any kind of properties... I have tried with different combination.

I am connecting SMTP Remote server (Server is not at localhost, its in LAN), with port 25 but it gives me the port error to 465, I dont know why ?

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: *RemoteIP*, port: 465; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

If anyone can help.

Thankx in advance.

Comment: can you ping the server and port using telnet? This seems to be a network or firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your mail server is actually using [SMTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS) on port 465 (although it's not the recommended port). If that is the case you can see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#gmail) an example of using JavaMail with SMTPS. Note the property `mail.smtps.host`; you also have the `mail.smtps.port` property to specify 465.